# Authenticating in Play without using routes

Tags: authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0, authorization

I've followed this tutorial for authentication and it works:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide4

But I was wondering if there was another way to do it so that the user can't just go to myapp.com/login and get the login screen even if they're already logged in. Is there a way to do this so I can go to the login screen but still have myapp.com as the route?

Comment: The controller function that outputs the login view will need to be able to check if the user is already authenticated, and if so, redirect them as if they had just logged in. It may be better to try a library like SecureSocial (http://securesocial.ws) or Deadbolt2 (https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2).

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Just have the controller method for route "/" display the login page instead of your landing page when the user is not logged in.

Say / routes to Application.index() and it has a function isLoggedIn() to check login status, you could do something like this:

```
public static index() {  

    if (isLoggedIn()) {  
        return ok (index.render());  
    }  
    else {  
        return ok (login.render());  
    }  
}
```